# how to display multiple post with different category in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

I need your help..
i've two categories in wordpress to display post
1. News
2. Projects

now i want to display last 3 post from both category like below..

> post1.
>     post2.
>     post3.
>   
>   
>   
>     post1.
>     post2.
>     post3.

Thank you guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping me...
I found solution which is working..
Thanks a lot for support..

```
$args1 = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 3,'post_type'=> 'post','post_status'=>'publish','orderby'=> 'post_date','order'=> 'DESC','suppress_filters' => true);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like below code it will fetch 3 post from each category

```
    <?php
wp_reset_query();

$cats = get_categories('');
foreach ($cats as $cat) :

if($cat->category_parent)  continue;
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'category_name' => $cat->slug,);

query_posts($args);

if (have_posts()) :
echo '<h2>Latest Posts in '.$cat->name.' Category</h2>';
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>     

<div>
 <h2>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 </h2>
</div>

<?php
  if ( is_category($vidcat) ) {  the_content();  }
  else { echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt(), '<a><strong>'); }
?>

<!-- this area is for the display of your posts the way you want it -->
<!-- i.e. title, exerpt(), etc. -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : echo '<h2>No Posts for '.$cat->name.' Category</h2>';?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

if you want to fetch exclude any category than pass the argument like this.

```
$args = array(
  'exclude' => '' //pass category id which your don't want to include.
)
$cats = get_categories($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$categoryids = array(add news category id,add projects category id);

$args = array(
'numberposts'     => 3,
'category__in'    => $categoryids,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'give the name of post types',
'post_status'     => 'publish' );

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );

foreach ($posts_array as $posts) {
  ....................
}

?>
```